# right way to use ->instance_url in php? (web api)

Tags: php, json, curl

I need to send in php curl the custom HEADER, post in XML or json, and return response in web api. Searching, i find this for try solving my problem with `not found requests`:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
LINE 112    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlCall->instance_url . $request);
    ..
```

refer to:

```
$urlCall = https://ip.andress/v1/requestActivateCode/;
```

and $request is a json params encoded (just test):

```
$params = array("RetailTransactionRequest" =>
    array(
        "code" => "0000002381237220",
        "amount" => $amount,
        "upc" => $upc,
        "transactionID" => "1234",
        "dateTime" => $xIncommDateTime,
        "retailerName" => $retailerName
    )
);
$request = json_encode($params);
```

Ok... but the result is:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/ubuntu/public_html/ip.adress/public/test.php on line 112
Curl error: Could not resolve host: {"RetailTransactionRequest":{"code":"0000002381237220","amount":"20.00","upc":"799366289999","transactionID":"1234","dateTime":"2015-06-08T09:09
```

And the info of **custom HEADER** is:
`bool(false)`

I need to post the array in server API and receive the answer from server in php file.... why dont work? thanks.

Comment: Is `$urlCall` a string or an object?

Comment: string with url for server of webservice

Answer (score 0):

There are two flaws in your code:

**1st**

`$urlCall`, as per your sayings, is a `string`. Therefore, there's no need for you to retrieve its value by using `$urlCall->instance_url`. Just use `$urlCall` altogether.

**2nd**

You must not append your `JSON` string to the URL you are calling. You need to use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Therefore, your code needs to be as such:

```
$urlCall = 'https://ip.andress/v1/requestActivateCode/';
$params = array("RetailTransactionRequest" =>
    array(
        "code" => "0000002381237220",
        "amount" => $amount,
        "upc" => $upc,
        "transactionID" => "1234",
        "dateTime" => $xIncommDateTime,
        "retailerName" => $retailerName
    )
);
$request = json_encode($params);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlCall); // note the use of $urlCall
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request); // this passes the JSON string to the server
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($request))                                                                       
); // this is to tell the server that the request contains JSON
```